# Converting jpeg to byte[], then inserting into SQL table

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, webforms, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a jpeg that I select from my disk into a byte array, then insert it into a table in SQL Server. I don't receive any errors, the record just isn't inserted...

I'm using a webform that allows you to select a Scheme code and Version from dropdown menus, then the corresponding data is retreived from the database and displayed on the webform. You can also create new records or update existing records. One of the fields in the database is a Logo, stored in varbinary(MAX).

Here is the onClick event, where the image that has been selected from the drive is copied to a temp folder, and from there it is converted into a byte array.

```
        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        //Div1.Visible = true;

        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(logoPrvw.Value);
        File.Copy(logoPrvw.Value, @"C:\TempImages\" + fileName, true);

        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\TempImages\" + fileName);
        byte[] logoBytes;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            logoBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }



            TemplateData data = new TemplateData(txtSchemeCode.Text, txtVersion.Text, txtComment.Text, txtTemplateId.Text, logoBytes);
            try
            {
                if (ddSchemeCode.SelectedIndex == 0 | ddVersion.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    DataClass.AddToData(data);
                }

                if (ddVersion.SelectedIndex != 0)
                {
                    DataClass.UpdateData(data);
                }
            }
        catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occured and the database was not updated.");
            }
```

Below is the code containing the the SQL instructions...

```
            public static TemplateData AddToData(TemplateData data)
    {
        string sqlAddNew = "INSERT INTO dbo.LetterTemplateCustomisation (Comment, TemplateId, Version, SchemeCode, Logo) ";
        sqlAddNew       += "VALUES ('" + data.Comment + "', " + data.TemplateId + ", " + data.Version + ", '" + data.SchemeCode + "'," + data.Logo + ")";

        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LettersDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlAddNew, connect);

        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        connect.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

        TemplateData tempData = null;
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            dr.Read();
            tempData = new TemplateData(dr);
        }

        dr.Close();
        connect.Close();

        return tempData;
    }
```

And lastly, the majority of a Data Class

```
    public class TemplateData
    {
    public byte[] Logo { get; set; }
    public string TemplateId { get; set; }
    public string SchemeCode { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public TemplateData(string schemeCode, string version, string comment, string templateID, byte[] logo)
    {
        SchemeCode = schemeCode;
        Version = version;
        Comment = comment;
        TemplateId = templateID;
        Logo = logo;

    }

    public TemplateData(SqlDataReader dr)
    {
        initialiseData();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
                Version = dr["Version"].ToString();
                Logo = (byte[])dr["Logo"];                 
                TemplateId = dr["TemplateId"].ToString();
                Comment = dr["Comment"].ToString();
                SchemeCode = dr["SchemeCode"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

I don't get any errors, the record just doesn't appear in the database. Like, none of it.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

I put a break point on 
`TemplateData data = new TemplateData(txtSchemeCode.Text, txtVersion.Text, txtComment.Text, txtTemplateId.Text, logoBytes);`
and logoBytes has bytes, they just aren't going anywhere.

Comment: try to use parameters instead of dynamic sql. the behaviour is quite odd but i would rule out any conversion/concatenation/whatever issue

Comment: Mr. Paolo sir, put that into an answer, and I shall tick it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make an attempt using sql parameters instead of concatenation:

```
string sqlAddNew = "INSERT INTO dbo.LetterTemplateCustomisation (Comment, TemplateId, Version, SchemeCode, Logo) ";
sqlAddNew       += "VALUES (@comment, @templateid, @version, @schemecode,@logo)";
```

then add the parameters to your command object using appropriate SQL data types:

```
    command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@comment", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = data.comment
    command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@templateid", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = data.templateid
    ...
    command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@logo", SqlDbType.Binary)).Value = data.logo
```

this is only a wild guess but should rule out any concatenation issue and hopefully make the actual issue visible.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this example, it show how to insert with parameterized command

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4f5s1we0(v=vs.110).aspx